# MySQL grant privilege for local db user to allow remote hosts using ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I am trying to login to MySQL DB as a root user and grant privilege for the local user. The root user already has the privilege for remote hosts to access. I want to provide the same for the local user. I have to use ansible only to achieve this. I am stuck with the format of `priv` of the ansible `mysql_user` module.
As per the ansible [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html) In the format `db.table:priv1` priv1 is the format based on MySQL `GRANT` statement.

The following is what I'm trying, but for all the combinations of the `priv` I am facing an error `invalid privileges string: Invalid privileges specified`. Any idea what could be the right raw string for `priv`?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Grant privilege to local user
      mysql_user:
        name: mylocaluser
        login_host: 10.10.10.11
        login_user: root
        login_password: 'myRootPassword'
        append_privs: true
        priv: "mydb.*:'mylocaluser'@'10.10.10.12'"
        state: present
```

Where `10.10.10.11` is the DB host and `10.10.10.12` is the remote host trying to access the DB using `mylocaluser`

Answer (score 0):

You're already specifying the user with `name`. You don't have to specify it again in the priv. The following creates a user with all privileges for all databases.

This user should be able to login from another system to this system.

```yaml
    - name: Grant privilege to local user
      mysql_user:
        name: mylocaluser
        login_host: 10.10.10.11
        login_user: root
        login_password: 'myRootPassword'
        append_privs: true
        priv: '*.*:ALL'
        state: present
```

As [per the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html#parameter-priv), priv values should be noted as: priv: `'DB.TABLES:PRIV1,PRIV2'`.